# why does using sum in a rails 3.1 scope result in an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have this scope:

```
scope :total_quantity, sum('quantity')
```

When I run:

```
MyModel.total_quantity
```

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `default_scoped?' for 4:Fixnum
```

Running the sum method directly works

```
MyModel.sum('quantity') # 4
```

I can't find any documentation on the default_scoped? method, or why it is being called here. Do you know if there is a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just try method instead of scope . It works like charm i also faced a same problem , but when i changed my scope to method its works fine . Below is working and tested code :)

```
def self.total_quantity
 sum('quantity')
end
```

Let me know if it works or not !
Thanks

Comment: Scope-compatible methods return a scoped object, not a number as is the case with `sum`. You need to use this approach with things that return a final value that can't be scoped further.

Comment: I also had the same issue where I tried to find count of objects via scope. Now its clear, thanks tadman

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
def self.total_quantity
 sum('quantity')
end
```

But I did not get reason for an error if I uses scope instead of method.